# How to find the period of $\tan2x + \cos2x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I need to find the period of the following trigonometric function:
$$f(x) = \tan2x + \cos2x$$

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please use MathJax for writing mathematical expressions.

Comment: Solve $f(x+T)=f(x)$ for the smallest nonzero $T$. In particular, $\tan 2T+\cos 2T=1$, but that's not sufficient.

Comment: $$\tan2(x+h)-\tan2x+\cos2(x+h)-\cos2x=\dfrac{\sin2h}{\cos2(x+h)\cos2x}-2\sin h\sin(2x+h)$$

$$=2\sin h\dfrac{\cos h-\cos2(x+h)\cos2x\sin(2x+h)}{\cos2(x+h)\cos2x}$$

Comment: $\tan n\theta$ has period of $\frac{\pi}{n}$ while $\cos n\theta$ has period of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.  The required period are the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of periods each term.  Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old, but still, I liked it and I think I can answer it.

First, note that
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \text{tan}(2x)+\text{cos}(2x)=\frac{2}{\text{cos}^2(2x)}-2\text{sin}(2x).$$

Since the following are all equivalent:
$$\frac{2}{\text{cos}^2(2x)}-2\text{sin}(2x)>0$$
$$\frac{2}{\text{cos}(2x)}>2\text{sin}(2x)\text{cos}(2x)$$
$$2>\text{cos}(2x)\text{sin}(4x),$$
the last being clearly true since $\text{cos}(2x)\leq 1$ and $\text{sin}(4x)\leq 1$, we then have the original function is strictly increasing when the derivative is not undefined, that is, when $x$ is not a half-integer multiple of $\frac{\pi}{4}$. So, the period has to be at least $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and the problem is solved when we verify such period works.

Useful [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=tan2x%2Bcos2x).